# El número de emails recibidos en Gmail no coincide con el que exportado por el código

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, gmail

En mi bandeja de entrada de Gmail tengo un total de 1994 email en recibidos. Dispongo de un código que exporta 3 campos del email (Id, Asunto y Fecha) a una hoja de Google sheets. Con él descarga un total de 1809 filas. ¿Alguien sabría decirme por qué existe esa diferencia? He probado con otra cuenta y ocurre lo mismo.

```
function getMail1(){
   var myspreadsheet = 
   SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
   var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

   var start = 0;
   var max = 249;
   var count =0;
   var row = mysheet.getLastRow()+1

   while(count < 8) 
   {

   var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start , max);
   var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 

   var froms = [];
   messages.get
   for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)

   {
   froms.push([messages[i][0].getId(),messages[i][0].getSubject(),messages[i][0].getDate()]);
   }

    mysheet.getRange(mysheet.getLastRow()+1,1,threads.length,3).setValues(froms);

    start =  start + 250;

    Logger.log(start);

    count++;
    Logger.log(count);

    }}
```

Aquí el registro de la ejecución:

```
22:38:59    Aviso   Se ha iniciado la ejecución
22:39:14    Información 250.0
22:39:14    Información 1.0
22:39:29    Información 500.0
22:39:29    Información 2.0
22:39:45    Información 750.0
22:39:45    Información 3.0
22:40:00    Información 1000.0
22:40:00    Información 4.0
22:40:17    Información 1250.0
22:40:17    Información 5.0
22:40:32    Información 1500.0
22:40:32    Información 6.0
22:40:48    Información 1750.0
22:40:48    Información 7.0
22:40:53    Información 2000.0
22:40:53    Información 8.0
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás contando lo que está en recibidos? ¿Se trata de conversaciones o de mensajes? ¿Porqué estásn limitando a 8 el número de iteraciones?

Comment: Aparentmente hay una línea incompleta --> `messages.get`. En lugar de agregar las filas en cada iteración, sería mejor que las agregaras al final, así sería mas rápido tu script y evitarías tener que estar leyendo el número de filas en cada iteración .

Comment: Hola @Rubén, cuento mensajes en recibidos, no conversaciones. Limito a 8 para llegar a 1992 mensajes totales exportados (249 x 8 ). Pero solo llega a 1809 filas.

Comment: Hola @Rubén Sobre tu segundo comentario, no sé como indicarlo en mi código para probarlo. ¿Me ayudas? mil Gracias

Comment: Hola, acabo de descubrir que mi código lee conversaciones no mensajes. Por eso, si no tengo activado vista conversación en gmail no me coincide el numero de emails recibidos, sin embargo si la tengo activada si me coincide. ¿Existe alguna manera de que lea mensajes recibidos en lugar de conversaciones?

Answer (score 0):

He estado analizando la solución al problema de exportar mensajes en lugar de conversaciones de mi bandeja de recibidos de Gmail. Lo he conseguido, pero los procesos son bastante lentos. No sé cómo mejorar mi código. ¿alguien me podria ayudar?

```
`function getMailToSheetMessages() {

 var myspreadsheet = 
 SpreadsheetApp.openById('1sruWW6lDDkRtW7ksuFxRiPvwqkHFMnnf753LJjTSDtw'); // Doc 
 Google de referencia
 var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; // Hoja 1

var start = 0;
var max = 1;
var count =0;

while(count < 11)

{

// var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start , max)[0];
var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start , max)[0];
// var messages = threads.getMessages();
var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(firstThread);   
var froms = [];
for (var i = 0; i < firstThread.getMessages().length; i++)

{
froms.push([messages[i].getSubject()_,messages[i].getDate(),messages[i].getFrom()]);
}
start++;
count++; 
mysheet.getRange(mysheet.getLastRow()+1,1, messages.length,3).setValues(froms);  

}}
```